# How can I set a custom user id upon a button click so that it tracks a person after a button click in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Is there a way to start tracking just people who click a certain button on my website and see where they go? If so how would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean with `where they go` ? somewhere in your website ?

Comment: If you want to track a specific user, there is no way to perform it with GA. It has to remain an anonymous tool.