# How can I give a group of users that click on a certain button a cookie so that I can follow them?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I'm wanting to track a group of users on my site by giving them a cookie or an ID that is trackable in google analytics. Does anyone know how to go about doing this? I talked to the google people for about an hour yesterday and didn't really get anywhere with them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: Also you posted this earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920535/how-can-i-set-a-custom-user-id-upon-a-button-click-so-that-it-tracks-a-person-af

Answer (score 0):

Consider using user scoped custom dimension. You can set specific value for users who click on a particular link or interact in some other way e.g. `ga('set','dimensionX', 'clicked link A')` and then build segment a segment in Analytics based on this value. More on custom dimension [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)